# git fetch - missing commits

Tags: linux, git

I am running `etckeeper` on two different machines, `boxA` and `boxB`. The OS, `etckeeper` repository and all, on `boxB` was copied from `boxA` back in January. In order to apply some setup changes made on `boxA` to `boxB`, I added the repository on `boxA` as a remote repository on `boxB` with the intention of doing some cherry picking, eg:

```
git remote add boxA ssh://boxA/etc
git fetch boxA
git cherry-pick xxxx  # never got this far
```

The problem is that the most recent commits are not available on `boxA`, only commits up until late February. So far I have tried:

- doing `git show` with one of the missing commit numbers - this is definitely not a problem with `git log` just not showing all the commits.
- copying the full `/etc` on `boxA` to `boxB` and adding/fetching it via its path - this is definitely not an issue somehow introduced by `ssh` (to complicate things I was using a script via the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to avoid creating a `root` login).
- `git fsck` on both repositories (no problems found).
- running the following command on copied version of both repositories (after doing a `git remote remove boxA` on `boxB` and before readding):

  ```
  git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0 \
    -c gc.rerereresolved=0 -c gc.rerereunresolved=0 -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc \
    --aggressive
  ```

How can I get `git fetch` to retrieve all of the commits?

Comment: What do you mean by most "recent commits are not available on boxA"? Not available in the remote branch remotes/boxA/master on boxB? What does git remote show boxA say? What does git fetch -v boxA say? (executed on boxB)

Comment: @UweGeuder, I managed to get to the bottom of this on my own. By commits not available, I mean that I wasn't able to view them via `git log boxA/master` or otherwise and not able to apply them with `git cherry-pick`.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here turned out to be that there was a [detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498458/why-did-git-set-us-on-no-branch) in the repository on `boxA` after an incomplete fix of a botched rebase. When this happens the output of `git branch` is as follows:

```
# git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

The [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953206/how-to-i-move-my-commits-from-no-branch-to-an-actual-branch) was simply to create a branch on `boxA` and then merge it:

```
git branch temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
git branch -d temp
```

After that all the commits on branch master (or at least what I thought was branch master) were available after doing another `git fetch`.

Comment: Makes sense when you mention it. Detached HEAD can be moved forward by committing, but no reference will be updated. Fetching works based on references.