# Version Control with Bitbucket (Git) throws error "no current branch"

Tags: git, version-control, upload, bitbucket, webstorm

I took over a project built with Cordova, Ionic and AngularJS to finally create a hybrid mobile app.

Source code is stored on bitbucket.org using Git; originally (before I took over) the code was downloaded from there.

On https://bitbucket.org v1.0 can be found; locally the code is v2.0.

Now I want to upload v2.0, but receive the message in IDE WebStorm 11.x: `Can´t update: no current branch. You are in 'detached' state, which means that you're not on any branch. Checkout a branch to make update possible.`

Note: Clicking the right little botton on the buttom showing versus `origin/develop` (which is the one on Bitbucket) and the on merge provides the message `Already up-to-date`, which is not true as files are(!) different.

`git reflog` says:

> 28ac44d HEAD@{0}: commit (merge): Merge remote-tracking branch
>   'origin/develop' into HEAD 338ffde HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from
>   develop to 338ffde8364f6bbf860d61b86eecbef8e84fe708 6399852 HEAD@{2}:
>   commit (merge): Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into
>   develop 05e819c HEAD@{3}: merge remotes/origin/master: Merge made by
>   the 'recursive' strategy. 338ffde HEAD@{4}: commit: Version 2.0.0
>   2c9fc80 HEAD@{5}: clone: from
>   https://joey@bitbucket.org/abcdefgh/ijklmnop.git

What do I have to do now?

Comment: This sounds very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498458/why-did-git-set-us-on-no-branch

Comment: Might be. However it is still not clear to me what do do now in order to avoid overwriting latest code...

Comment: You are, in your IDE, not on a (local) branch.  You've merged `origin/develop` (which is not a *local* branch, it's a *remote-tracking* branch, which is not a branch, or at least, not the right kind of branch, because git people decided to use the word "branch" to mean multiple different things... [if at this point you want to go "arrgh" I fully agree with you :) ]).  You need to create a (local) branch.  I have no idea how to do that in your IDE, I only know how to use the command line.

Comment: Thanks, torek, that helped.